# How to transfer message between different request in web.py?

Tags: python, web.py

In web.py, I use web.seeother() to redirect to another page, is there a way to transfer some message to that page too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass globals to the template engine and link it to your session:

```
session = web.session.Session(app,web.session.DiskStore('sessions'), initializer={'message': ""})
render = web.template.render('templates/', globals={'context': session}, base='layout')
```

inside your template:

```
$if context.message:
  <div id="messageBox">
  $context.message
  </div>
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a Get Variable:
web.seeother('/somepage?message=hello')

bye

Comment: That's a good idea. But the url gets ugly if the message is long. Are there any other solution?